# Regular Expressions: Unbalanced parenthesis error

Tags: regex

Why does the following regular expression leads to an 'unbalanced parenthesis error'?

```
[x(?:[0-9])]
```

I know this one doesn't make sense. I am working on a larger expression and found this as a minimal working example that produces the error. I want to realize a choice with a nested inner choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to do the whole thing inside a character class created by the square brackets `[...]`. What the Regex sees is

```
[x(?:[0-9]
```

As one character class you're trying to match, followed by

```
)]
```

Which makes no sense, since the right-parenthesis is meaningless without a left.

What you might be trying to do is match a character class followed by an uncaptured digit:

```
[x](?:[0-9])
```

If you're trying to force this inside the square brackets, then I'm guessing that you want to match several different scenarios, such as:

```
[xyz](?:[0-4])|[abc](?:[5-9])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Z63CVGjUJeTL4bIP)

Answer (score 3):

`[…]` creates a character class, which matches a single character in the set of characters that you specify within the braces. Character classes cannot *contain* groups, quantifiers, assertions, etc. Everything inside the character class is interpreted as a literal character, character range, or a predefined character set (like `\s` but not `.`)

So your pattern recognizes this as a character class `[x(?:[0-9]` (which matches a single `x`, `(`, `?`, `:`, `[`, or any character from `0` to `9`), followed by `)]`. But the `)` is not escaped and is not matched with a corresponding `(`, and so it produces an error.

It's likely you just want:

```
x[0-9]
```

This will match an `x` followed by a single digit from `0` to `9`.